# Whenever someone enchants a creature, do they "control" that creature

Tags: magic-the-gathering

For example, if someone casts [claustrophobia](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bclaustrophobia%5d) on my creature, do they control it?

Comment: No, but the player that cast the Enchantment controls the Enchantment, even if it enchants an opponent's permanent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless the enchantment specifically grants them control they do not. All that the enchantment that you mentioned does is tap the creature and prevent it from untapping as normal.

Comment: Thanks! Can I also perform other actions on it with an instant? For example, I wanted to play rallying roar to untap it.

Comment: Click on tue link that I edited into your question and you will find more information.

Comment: @BrandonRoberts of course, Claustrophobia taps the card and only prevents it from untapping at the untap step, if it is untapped by any other effect, it stays untapped until tapped again, at which point it stays tapped again. There are many cards that do the same, with different costs and targeting rules (permanent vs creature). Similar card [Curse of Chains](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=146079) taps it every turn, so it would play a little differently, but it would untap each turn letting you tap it for effects before it taps itself.